# How to insert values in temp table on multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code. Can I insert values into a temp table multiple times? I have list of ids (i.e. 1000 ids). I want to insert this by loop.

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(col1 INT)

FOR (@ids IS NOT NULL) {
    INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(@ids)
}

SELECT * FROM @tempTable
```

Comment: Yes. you can insert. did you facing any problem with that?

Comment: you mean insert the same value into the temp table 1000 times ?

Answer (score 2):

Even though it is possible using `WHILE` loop I will suggest you to go with *SET Based approach*

Why cant you just do this

```
INSERT INTO @tempTable (ID)
select Id from yourlist
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is not support FOR loop. You need to use WHILE loop instead.

[SQL Server Looping](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/loops/for_loop.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while statement as said Jitendra Tiwari:

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(col1 INT)

DECLARE @num int 
SET  @num = 1
WHILE @num <= 1000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES (@num) --(@ids)
    SET @num = @num + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @tempTable
```